# sequential deferred promise with ajax call running out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If you look at showResults(), you will see it first creates a promise, then runs getSelectedIds() which returns a promise, then it makes the api call with those selected ids, which is an ajax call, then console logs `sr df3 finished`.  the problem im having an extreme hard time figuring out is i think i have some missing return statements somewhere, so the promise is getting resolved too early or something.

Can somebody PLEASE spot where im going wrong here, and tell me what is needed in either the getApi ajax call or the previous, or following event so that "sr df3 finished" DOES NOT happen until after the ajax call has returned its promise.

```
app.core.getSelectedIds = function(){

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    //eliminates having to make an unnecessary ajax call if we already have them
    if( $.isEmptyObject(app.core.selectedIds) ){

        //gather up selected ids
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (key, value) {

            //look for checked checkboxes only
            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).hasClass('results')) {

                //get id from hidden input next to checkbox, set ids into an object for later use
                stdIds[key] = $(this).next().attr('value');
            }
        });

        app.core.selectedIds = stdIds;
    }

    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
};

 app.test.getApi = function(newToken, nextPageNum){

    var df1,df2;

    if(nextPageNum){ app.test.nextPageNum = nextPageNum; }

    df1 = app.test.ajaxCall1();

    df2 = df1.then( function(){
            console.log('test df2 started');
            console.log(app.test.standardsObj); //the ajax calls results after being applied to the methods property
    });

    df2.done(function(){
            console.log('test df2 finished');
    });
};

app.ui.showResults = function(newToken){

    var df1,df2,df3;

    df1 = $.Deferred();

    df2 = df1.then(function(){
            console.log('sr df2 started');
            return app.core.getSelectedIds(); //is a promise
    });

    df2.done(function(){
            console.log(app.core.selectedIds);
            console.log('sr df2 finished');
    });

    df3 = df2.then(function(){
            console.log('sr df3 started');
            app.test.getApi(newToken);
    });

    df3.done(function(){
            console.log('sr df3 finished');
    });

    df1.resolve();
};

app.test.ajaxCall1 = function(){

    var idArr = [];

    //For now set up an array to cast those values to
    $.each(app.core.selectedIds, function( key, value ){

        idArr[key] = value;
    });

    return app.core.methodByRoute('ajax_call_1', {ids: idArr}, 'GET')
        .done(function(retrievedResults){

            app.test.standardsObj = retrievedResults;
        })
};
```

console log output is

```
sr df2 started
Object { 1="498", 2="501", 3="502", more...}
sr df2 finished 
sr df3 started 
sr df3 finished 
test df2 started 
["valid data"] 
test df2 finished
```

Comment: please note, i added the `app.test.ajaxCall1` method above, incase needed to see, it basically runs an async curl request.  if you feel the problem might be in the methodByRoute() i can add that here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.core.getSelectedIds = function(){
>     var dfd = $.Deferred();
>     …
>     dfd.resolve();
>     return dfd.promise();
> }
> ```

Looks like this function doesn't need to return a promise at all if it doesn't do anything asynchronous, and would resolve the deferred immediately anyway?

> i think i have some missing return statements somewhere

Yes, exactly. The basic rule is: **`return` a promise from every function that does something asynchronous**. In your case, that includes the `app.test.getApi` function and the `df2.then(function(){…})` callback that calls it - if the callback doesn't return anything, `df3` is resolved immediately after `df2`, as it doesn't know what to wait for.

Btw, you don't need that `df1` - just start the chain with the first promise that a function returns.

```
app.core.getSelectedIds = function() {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(app.core.selectedIds)) {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (key, value) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).hasClass('results')) {
                stdIds[key] = $(this).next().attr('value');
            }
        });
        app.core.selectedIds = stdIds;
    }
    return $.when(app.core.selectedIds); // a promise. just to start the chain.
                                         // maybe this function needs to do
                                         // something async in the future
};

app.test.getApi = function(newToken, nextPageNum) {
    if (nextPageNum) {
        app.test.nextPageNum = nextPageNum;
    }
    var df1 = app.test.ajaxCall1();
    var df2 = df1.then( function(){
            console.log('test df2 started');
            console.log(app.test.standardsObj); //the ajax calls results after being applied to the methods property
    });
    df2.done(function(){
            console.log('test df2 finished');
    });
    return df2;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^
};

app.ui.showResults = function(newToken) {
    var df1 =app.core.getSelectedIds(); // is a promise
    df1.done(function() {
        console.log(app.core.selectedIds);
        console.log('sr df2 finished');
    });
    var df2 = df1.then(function() {
        console.log('sr df2 started');
        return app.test.getApi(newToken);
//      ^^^^^^
    });
    df2.done(function(){
        console.log('sr df2 finished');
    });
    return df2;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ just for convenience, if we want to chain something
//              after a .showResults() call
};
```

Comment: man i cant thank you enough.  i dont think the $.wait() is necessary, i like to create the deferred for easier reading in df1, and most importantly, YOU FOUND the magical return i was missing in `showResults()` `return $.when(app.core.selectedIds);` and `return df2;` in  `app.test.getApi`.  i want to cuss up a storm right now since that was so frustrating yesterday, and the day before, and the .... thanks!    removing the `df1.resolve()` and replacing with `return df2;` in `app.ui.showResults()` simply breaks it.

Comment: clarifying my last point there, removing the `df1.resolve()` and replacing with `return df2;` in `app.ui.showResults()` simply breaks it.  whats going on there?  doesnt it need to be resolved?  is there any way i can paste the revised code in here without answering my own question?

Comment: Notice that I also removed `df1 = $.Deferred(); df1.then(function(){…`. If you still have that in your code but remove `df1.resolve()` then it won't work of course.

Comment: ok i see yes.  i prefer to have that portion in there for now for better separation until i get better at using deferreds.  thanks for pointing that out.